# Получить список городов подгружаемый динамически

Tags: angularjs

Нужна помощь в решении задачи — разобраться в логике простого php-скрипта:

```
<?php
class Controller {
/**
 * Выводит в буфер JSON со списком городов
 * @return void
 */
public function getCityList() {

    $data = array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Москва',
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Мурманск',
        ),

    );

    echo json_encode($data);
}

/**
 * Выводит в буфер JSON с данными о городе, принимая ID города
 * @return void
 */
public function getCityData() {


    $data = array(
        1 => array(
            'founding_date' => 1147,
            'population' => 12197596,
            'area' => 2561.5,
        ),
        2 => array(
            'founding_date' => 1916,
    'population' => 305236,
            'area' => 154.4,
        ),

    );

    if (!isset($_GET['id']) || !isset($data[$_GET['id']])) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request', 400);
        die();
    }



    echo json_encode($data[$_GET['id']]);
}

}

$controller = new Controller;

if (!isset($_GET['action']) || !method_exists($controller, $_GET['action'])) {
     header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request', 400);
     die();
}
$controller->{$_GET['action']}();
?>
```

1. В первом блоке должен быть select, позволяющий выбрать город, во втором блоке - форма с данными города.
2. С помощью Angular создать мини приложение, в котором:
   Данные в select должны подгружаться динамически;
   При выборе города из списка, id города отправляется на сервер для получения данных о городе. Полученные данные вставляются в форму.

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? Что не получается?

Comment: мне совет нужен, возможно есть аналогичные решения, либо подсказать что делать. Вопрос не в том что не получается, я просто хочу научится решать задачи.Для меня эта задача совершенно новая.